# Short variable declaration and "variable declared and not used" error

Tags: go

I've stumbled across a strange issue where the code below fails to compile:

```
func main() {
    var val reflect.Value
    var tm time.Time

    if tm, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-09-11T17:50:54.247Z"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    val = reflect.ValueOf(tm)

    fmt.Println(val, tm, reflect.TypeOf(tm))
}
```

with the error (the code is what linter recommends).:

```
$ go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:13:5: tm declared and not used
```

Note the `tm` variable is indeed used.

If however I add an else block - everything compiles as expected:

```
func main() {
    var val reflect.Value
    var tm time.Time

    if tm, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-09-11T17:50:54.247Z"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        val = reflect.ValueOf(tm)
    }

    fmt.Println(val, tm, reflect.TypeOf(tm))
}
```

This looks like a bug in the compiler or perhaps a known issue? Any idea? (I'm using go 1.11)

edit: to all respondends so far. As per: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
>   body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
>   is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

Comment: whoever left a downvote - can you please elaborate why? Enlighten me

Comment: WRT the quote from GO docs: critical keyword here is 'same block'. `if` opens a new nested block, so this doesn't apply (see my answer for a more detailed explanation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This part:

```
if tm, err := time.Parse(...)
```

creates a **new** variable `tm` that has scope only within the `if` statement - it is NOT the one you declared as `var tm time.Time`.

This new variable is not used within the `if`, therefore you get the error. Note you also don't get the outer-level `tm` assigned, so `fmt.Println` will print the zero time, not what time.Parse returned.

To fix this:
declare `err` and change your `if` to read:

```
var err error
if tm, err = time.Parse(...)
```

NOTE this is a subtle thing in GO and a fairly common source of mistakes. The `:=` statement can in fact be used with a mix of variables that are already declared and one or more *new* variables - if the already-declared ones are in the *same lexical scope*. Then, only the new ones are auto-declared by `:=` and the rest are just assigned (as with `=`). However, if you use `:=` in a new scope, then ALL variables are declared in that scope and mask any outer-scope variables with the same name (such as in an `if`; note that the `if` condition is not inside the braces, but is still considered as if it were within the `{code}` block; same happens with the `for` and other compound statements in GO).

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement declares a new variable `tm` that exists only within the scope of the `if` block and is indeed never used:

```
if tm, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-09-11T17:50:54.247Z"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

In Go, `:=` declares a *new* variable and initializes it. You probably meant:

```
func main() {
    var val reflect.Value
    var tm time.Time
    var err error

    // Note the change to normal assignment here instead of :=
    if tm, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-09-11T17:50:54.247Z"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    val = reflect.ValueOf(tm)

    fmt.Println(val, tm, reflect.TypeOf(tm))
}
```

The `:=` shortcut operator is demonstrated in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/10) and explained in [the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), the latter of which includes:

> It is shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types:
>
> `"var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .`

Scoping is explained in [the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) as well.

Comment: Please read the go, documentation - := operator ASSIGNS the existing variables OR declares new ones. The condition is that at least one variable must be new.

Comment: I've read it, and I have extensive experience with Go, which is how I identified your issue. This is the fix. Consider trying it before arguing against it.

Comment: Added further documentation references for clarity.

Comment: I am not argueing that it's not going to work. I'm argueing that what I am doing is invalid Go. In the Go spec you referenced, please read: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Comment: Yes, I've read it - in fact, I had linked to the exact same section in this answer already. But you're right, what you're doing is invalid Go. Both the answers you've received are the same, and both are correct. I hope this helps you to resolve your issue and better understand the Go language.

Comment: @Alex, it is true that `:=` can both assign existing vars and declare new ones - but the docs clearly show that this works only if the declarations are in the same scope. In your case `if` opens a new scope, so none of the existing declarations (such as your `var tm`) are taken into account and everything on the left of `:=` is newly-declared.

Comment: @Adrian Applogies for the 'RTFM' responses. Indeed I did miscomprehend that bit in the spec. I'm new to go and apparently have a lot to learn. Event though I've accepted Leo K's answer because it was clearer(imo) and helped me understand the issue better, I still appreciate your quick response. Thanks.